# Can someone explain in simple terms how to understand and calculate n to the power of i for n > 1?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know how to add, subtract, multiply and divide any number by a complex number, but it is mysterious how one go about calculating $2$ to the power of $i$ for example. I would like to understand from the beginning. What is the logic behind a number elevated to the power of $i$?

Comment: Do you know about Taylor series? Analytic continuation?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: What do you mean "what is the logic behind a number elevated to the power of $i$"? What is the logic behind a number elevated to the power of $2\pi+\sqrt 2$?

Comment: By logic I mean rationale.

Comment: UNCLEAR !!!??? You guys are idiots! Adam Hughes is an total idiot!

Answer (score 2):

Complex exponentiation is defined by

$$z^w = e^{w\log z}$$

Because the expression $\log z$ assumes a countably infinite number of distinct values (differing by integral multiples of $2\pi i$), there typically exist more than one value of the original expression.

So the possible values of $2^i$ are

$$e^{i\log 2} = e^{i(\ln 2 -2k\pi i)} = e^{2k\pi + i\ln 2 } = e^{2k\pi}(\cos\ln2 + i\sin\ln 2)$$

for integral $k$ (note: "$\ln$" denotes the real-valued function of a positive real number).

Comment: so there are infinite values for 2 to the power of i ?

Comment: @MattMath for positive real numbers most of the time you take the real logarithm, which makes $a^z$ unique again.This is the case e. g. when defining $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\geq1} n^{-s}$.

Comment: Can someone translate to human terms what Zardo said?

Comment: When $a$ is a real number, you usually define $a^z = \exp(z \ln a)$ by using the logarithm $\ln: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$, where there is no ambiguity about the logarithm. This is how you interpret the series representation of the Riemann $\zeta$ function for $\Re s > 1$.

Comment: Yes, there are an infinite number of distinct values for this expression. That's just because there are an infinite number of distinct values of the logarithm of any (nonzero) complex number. This is typical behavior where complex exponents are involved. One often selects a principal value for the logarithm, which then produces a principal value for the expression. This is most often the value of the log with $\arg z \in(-\pi,\pi]$ but usage varies.

Answer (score 0):

A cute way of looking at it is to use the formula $$e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$ for $\theta$ in radians. There are tricks to prove this. The way I'd at least justify it to myself without actually proving it, though, is to take the derivative of the right side, and get $i$ times the original right side back, just like taking the derivative of the left side where you get $i$ times the original left side back. This is actually something like how Euler might have done it back in the day, but times have changed and we've decided this isn't good enough for us anymore.

Notice that we can now get rules for things like $2^i$ by taking logarithms and playing around.